# Backup e Restor Mongodb - metodos

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Estou iniciando no mongodb, plataforma linux. gostaria de saber qual a melhor estratégia de backup já que:

Data import e Export - são utilizados para saidas em cvs ou json
 Mongodump e Mongorestore - são usados para pequenas bases.

Enfim, qual a melhor ferramenta?

Answer (score 1):

A [página da documentação oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) menciona várias formas. Desconsiderando a ferramenta oficial de manutenção, o [Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) que é pago por servidor, você tem duas opções (três dependendo do sistema operacional/infraestrutura):

1. Usar mongodump/mongorestore.
2. Copiar os arquivos manualmente.
3. Usar snapshot do disco onde estão os teus dados (e journal).

O dump/restore funciona bem somente em bases pequenas porque a complexidade que é adicionada quando você tem vários shards, por exemplo, torna inviável o gerenciamento da integridade/sincronização dos backups.

Se você está executando um conjunto de replicação (replica set), não vejo problema em fazer backup com dump/restore. Considerando que você use a opção --oplog para que as alterações que estão sendo feitas durante o dump sejam incluídas, e depois no restore use --oplogReplay.

Copiar os arquivos manualmente envolve parar qualquer escrita no(s) servidor(es) pois você está copiando vários arquivos, e essa não é uma operação atômica.

No caso dos snapshots você pode usar sem problemas desde que o journaling esteja ativo (é o padrão), sem isso não há garantia que seu snapshot vai ser válido. Se você usar essa opção em um sharded cluster, é necessário parar o balancer e fazer o snapshot de todos os shards e dos servidores de configuração aproximadamente ao mesmo tempo.